# PHP break database contents into individual keyword?

Tags: php

I'm building a keyword search's suggestion box and currently I'm receiving the whole contents of an article (title, author, tags, categories, article contents)
which will be something like:

```
 Likable Guy at the Party SSCOTT CHRISTIAN Don't try to be Johnny Depp at the Oscars; just stick to a tux, with a tuxedo shirt, black bow tie, trousers with a satin stripe and, preferably, patent leather shoes. (If it's good enough for 007, it's good enough for you.) Fashion style runway
```

Before being encode into json to feed into real time front end, how do you break individual word so that it appear something like so:

```
Likable, Guy, at, the, Party, SSCOTT, CHRISTIAN, Don't, try, to, be, Johnny, Depp.......
```

Comment: what you tried? Btw I'd use regexp for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `explode(' ', $sentence)` then `implode` to add the commas, however you will get some undesirable results with punctuation:

```
$s = implode(', ', explode(' ', $s));
```

Will output:

> Likable, Guy, at, the, Party, SSCOTT, CHRISTIAN, Don't, try, to, be,
>   Johnny, Depp, at, the, Oscars;, just, stick, to, a, tux,, with, a,
>   tuxedo, shirt,, black, bow, tie,, trousers, with, a, satin, stripe,
>   and,, preferably,, patent, leather, shoes., (If, it's, good, enough,
>   for, 007,, it's, good, enough, for, you.), Fashion, style, runway

Another option is to strip the punctuation first. You can do this with `preg_replace` to keep letters and apostrophe only:

```
$s = preg_replace("/[^a-z']+/i", ' ', $s); 
$s = implode(', ', explode(' ', $s));
```

Which will output:

> Likable, Guy, at, the, Party, SSCOTT, CHRISTIAN, Don't, try, to, be,
>   Johnny, Depp, at, the, Oscars, just, stick, to, a, tux, with, a,
>   tuxedo, shirt, black, bow, tie, trousers, with, a, satin, stripe, and,
>   preferably, patent, leather, shoes, If, it's, good, enough, for, it's,
>   good, enough, for, you, Fashion, style, runway

Answer (score 0):

```
implode (', ', explode (' ',$sentence));
```

Comment: Wrong way around `implode(', ', explode(' ',$sentence));`